# how to add a column into a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add a column of '1's on all my rows of first column...
For example, before:

```
9 8 4
3 4 5
3 2 1
```

after:

```
1 9 8 4
1 3 4 5
1 3 2 1
```

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

training = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None)
training
training.shape
```

Output = `(300, 14)`

To make data into a matrix:

```
trainingData = training.values
```

Insert a column of 1's in the first column on all rows

```
featureVector = np.insert(featureVector, 0, 1, axis=0)
```

When I print the variable featureVector, I don't see the 1's...how can I do this or fix it?

Comment: Try with axis=1, since you want to change the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
array = training.values
np.concatenate(([np.ones(len(array))],array.T),axis=0).T
```

Answer (score 1):

With [**`numpy.insert()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) routine:

```
import numpy as np

training = np.loadtxt('data.csv', dtype=int)
training = np.insert(training, 0, 1, axis=1)
print(training)
```

The output:

```
[[1 9 8 4]
 [1 3 4 5]
 [1 3 2 1]]
```

Comment: So basically he/she had the axis wrong. Nice one! +1

Comment: just curious, why do you use np.loadtxt() over pd.read_csv? can np.loadtxt()  handle large data sets?

Comment: @KatZee, just seen that simple input data and thought that the job could be done with single `numpy` module(without `pandas`). Of course, you may continue to use pandas

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate a 1-column matrix and `training` :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> training = np.array([9, 8, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1]).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.concatenate((np.ones((training.shape[1], training)), a), axis=1)
array([[ 1.,  9.,  8.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.,  1.]])
```

`axis=1` is used to specify that a column should be added. Otherwise:

```
>>> np.concatenate(([[1,1,1]], training), axis=0)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [9, 8, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

You could also use `column_stack`:

```
>>> np.column_stack((np.ones(training.shape[1]), training))
array([[ 1.,  9.,  8.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: would I have to make a loop if I wanted to change 300 rows in the first column?